# How do I get the classical routing conventions in Core?

Tags: asp.net-core

I am building a Web API with Core 2 and my methods are named like:

```
public ActionResult<xxx> Get()
public void Post(...)
// etc
```

I can't seem to make asp.net route to them, unless I specify the verb, which I don't want to - `[HttpGet], [HttpPost]`, etc

I've tried adding `[assembly: ApiConventionType(typeof(DefaultApiConventions))]` on top of the `Startup` class, but doesn't seem to do the trick.

This works perfectly in ASP.NET Web API.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but seems like you can install this Nuget package to get the function name -> HTTP method convention: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim/.

The convention you're looking for is this one: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/a6199bbfbab05583f987bae322fb04566841aaea/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim/Conventions/WebApiActionConventionsApplicationModelConvention.cs#L85

Seems like you add it in `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddMvc().AddWebApiConventions();
```